# Uploading security.json file in zookeerper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I am facing issues in uploading security..json file in zookeeper. Even though when i am running the zkcli.sh script, it is getting executed without issues.

But when i am validating it by the following url, it is giving me error as " no authorization configured".

Url to validate:
 ip address:port/solr/admin/authentication

Comment: What does your security.json file look like?

Comment: It started working... thanks!

Comment: @Pandeyji , can you please share the command you used to upload security.json to zookeeper